# Swift 4 - Collection View Apply Section insets to header?

Tags: ios, swift

I am using a Collection View and I am able to add Section insets to the cells inside the collection view, but it appears not to be applying to the Collection Views reusable view, is there away to set section insets for reusable views?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {


        if(kind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter)
        {
            let footerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "ReviewsFooter", for: indexPath) as! ReviewFooterCell

            footerView.reviewFooterDelegate = self

            return footerView
        }
        else if(kind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader)
        {
            let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "ReviewHeader", for: indexPath) as! ReviewHeaderCell

            headerView.totalReviews.text = "Total Reviews: " + String(self.reviews.count)

            return headerView
        }

        fatalError()

    }
```

Comment: Section Inset is for the whole section and not for the cell or views in that section.

Comment: Section insets is for cells usage, if you want more advance behavior, you need to do custom [UICollectionViewLayout](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let's be clear on what exactly is *Section Insets*.

> Section insets are margins applied only to the items in the section.
>   They represent the distance between the header view and the first line
>   of items and between the last line of items and the footer view. They
>   also indicate the spacing on either side of a single line of items.
>   They do not affect the size of the headers or footers themselves.

Here is how you can add `insets` of a `section` in `collectionView`,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 20, right: 20)
}
```